# In Magento 1.5 is it possible to import products using CSV with custom options?

Tags: magento

Magento allows you to set custom options for products -- for example, Deluxe version of a product that is $15 more expensive.

Previous versions of Magento prior to 1.5 required a hack to import custom options. I understand that 1.5 allows importing of custom options. However the Magento website has zero documentation.

Can anyone explain how to import a CSV file with products using custom options?

Comment: could be a configurable product... create two simple versions. one is the deluxe version, one is the simple version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to give one of your products a custom option and then export, you will see in the exported file how it works.

I have a custom Manufacturer field, in the csv this just exports as the header "manufacturer".